# variadic template struct, recursive type declaration, is it possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

there!

There is any way to declare a type recursively? I was almost there but I got a compile error.

I'm designing a simple template to determine the optimal type for storing the result of operating mixed type stuff.

OP_T<> Use case example:

```
typename OP_T<char, float, int>::M var //var is actually a float
```

Code

```
template <typename ...T>
struct OP_T{};

template <typename T0, typename T1>
struct OP_T<T0, T1> {
    using M = typename x_traits<T0, T1>::MULT_T;
};

template <typename T0, typename ...Ts>
struct OP_T<T0, Ts...> {
    using M = typename OP_T<T0, Ts...>::M; // error: 'M' is not a member of 'OP_T' 
};
```

This is x_traits simplified

```
template<typename T>
struct x_traits_default {
    typedef T MULT_T;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct x_traits {};

template<typename T2>
struct x_traits<double, T2> : public x_traits_default<double> {};

template<typename T1>
struct x_traits<T1, double> : public x_traits_default<double> {};
```

Here you can find a more detailed use case example (but still simplified):
https://godbolt.org/z/jbcahq

Comment: Shouldn't `using M = typename OP_T<T0, Ts...>::M;` be `using M = typename OP_T<Ts...>::M;`? Otherwise it's referencing itself

Comment: a [mre] would be helpful too

Comment: you get similar problem with `struct foo { using M = foo:M; };` what should `M` be?

Comment: Can you explain what this exactly should do (question and code doesn't explain that)? Looks like that this `x_traits` suppose to define some result type of some operation, in such case you made this over-complicated and `declttype` can do that in one line. Examples of usages could be very helpful and demo on site like https://godbolt.org/ would be great.

Comment: You don't need a `typename` in your example.

Comment: We could still do with a [mre], `MULT_T` is not declared

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you meant something like this:

```
template <typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct OP_T<T0, Ts...> {
    using M = typename OP_T<T0, typename OP_T<Ts...>::M>::M;
};
```

Now `OP_T<T1, T2, ...>::M` will be a type obtained from the pack `T1, T2, ...` by the application of the "reduction" binary metafunction `x_traits<S, T>::MULT_T`, similar in spirit to what `std::accumulate` with a custom binary operation does.

Comment: Answer starting with `I guess you meant` shows shortcomings of question.

Comment: @MarekR, agree. But I dared to post the answer anyway because I strongly believe that my guess is correct.

Comment: @Evg, Nice guess;). I'm sorry, next time I will try to explain it better!

Answer (score 2):

<del>I suspect that</del>Since you need result type of some chained operation this could look like this (using `C++17` fold expression):

```cpp
template<typename ...Ts>
using mutiplication_result_t = decltype((std::declval<Ts>() * ...));
```

Same for C++11:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename ...Ts>
struct mutiplication_result
{ 
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T1>() * std::declval<typename mutiplication_result<Ts ...>::type>());
};

template<typename T>
struct mutiplication_result<T>
{ 
    using type = typename std::decay<T>::type;
};

template<typename ...Ts>
using mutiplication_result_t = typename mutiplication_result<Ts...>::type;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qnx1Y8

Comment: Answer starting with `I suspect` .... only OP knows what OP knows ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818, we need a third one. :)

Comment: Yes I know :). Done on purpose.

Comment: Nice answer @MarekR, but unfortunately the * operator is not overloaded in the right way on the desired types (see, complete example: https://godbolt.org/z/jbcahq).  (Constructor test http://cpp.sh/2dapw)

Comment: `operator*` was selected as an example. This can be done for any function/method. Advantage is that you do not have to map manually type relations.

Comment: Yep @MarekR nice trick. Sorry, I pasted the wrong link (Operator * overload test http://cpp.sh/5pql4)